# Concise way to change object across multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I'm looking to know if changing an object in one array will change it in others.

I have an array of tasks, each of which is a hash object with `:id, :user, :task`

I then use `duplicates = tasks.select{|task| sample code}` to select some tasks from that array.

If I change a task in `duplicates`, will it change in `tasks` as well? If not, are there any good ways to search for that same task?

Comment: I tested this in console and it seems to change across arrays. My guess is that each array only contains pointers to the objects, as opposed to the objects themselves. This way the same exact object is effectively in both arrays. Can someone confirm this?

Leaving this question up in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as "changing an object across arrays". An object does not know and does not care whether it is in an array or not.

Changing an object changes an object. Period. If that object is contained in multiple arrays, then you will observe that change, regardless of how you obtain the object. But it is not "changed across arrays". It is simply changed.

If you cut your hair, everybody who looks at you will observe that your hair is short, regardless of whether they perceive you as "student #1234", "the quarterback of the Backwater Swamprats", or "the youngest son of the Smith family". What reference is used to address you has no bearing on whether your hair is short or not.